# What's going on with the Blood-Sucker?

Tags: anjaan-special-crimes-unit

On the TV show *Anjaan: Special Crimes Unit*, at one point Aditi and Vikrant investigate a case of murders by a supposed "Blood-Sucker," more or less a vampire. At the end of the episode, we see that Parvati, the mother of the bullied girl at the center of the episode's plot, seems to be behind the murders. However, we *also* see that the Blood-Sucker may still exist, seemingly having killed Gopal. Left unaddressed is the nature of the relationship of Parvati's family to the Blood-Sucker.

- What and who is the Blood-Sucker? Is it a vengeful ghost (the ghost of Parvati's daughter) like many we've seen? The fact that we saw her ghost at the end points to this. *However*, if this is so, how does Parvati know about it, enough to cover the mirrors with paper? Is she feeding blood to an incorporeal spirit, too? And why would Parvati's mother call her granddaughter just "Blood-Sucker" instead of by name?
- Is the Blood-Sucker friends with Parvati and her mother? Further, if the family really is on good terms with the Blood-Sucker, which clearly also wants, why is Parvati risking herself to kill the boys in a manner similar to that of the Blood-Sucker, instead of letting the creature do it?

In short, what is going on with this creature? What is its nature and motivation?